# Hide textarea if user clicks outside it, but keep it visible on mouse leave outside it after selecting the text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textarea which should get hidden if the user clicks outside it, and remains visible if he clicks inside the textarea.

The problem is that when the user selects the text of the textarea and leaves the mouse outside it, the textarea gets hidden and he cannot copy the text anymore.

How can I fix this?

[**Live JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxnNB/)

HTML:

```
<span>Show textarea</span>

<div>
    <textarea>Text in textarea</textarea>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("span").on("click", function () {
    $("textarea").show();
});


$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("div");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $("textarea").hide();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
textarea {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `mousedown()` event instead

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxnNB/7/)

Answer (score 1):

More full proof (check if mouse down was outside and hide on mouse up), but would need optimization:
http://jsfiddle.net/YqJ48/

```
(function() {

$("span").on("click", function () {
    $("textarea").show();
});

var wasDown = false;

$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    wasDown = false;
    var container = $("div");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        wasDown = true;
    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("div");

    if (wasDown && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $("textarea").hide();
    }
});

})()
```

EDIT: If you don't want to be able to cancel hiding just use:

```
$("span").on("click", function () {
    $("textarea").show();
});

$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    var container = $("div");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $("textarea").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Surely it's as simple as: if the mouse goes down in the textarea, don't hide it, if it doesn't, hide it. Why the need for all the additional logic? I'm curious

Comment: You can "cancel" hidding if you move from outside inside. I think that was the purpose of using mouse up not mouse down. Otherwise you could just use mouse down.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**HTML**

```
<span>Show textarea</span>

<div id="backGround">
    <textarea>Text in textarea</textarea>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#backGround').click(function () {

 $("textarea").hide();
```

});

Comment: The textarea is inside backGround, so if I click on the textarea it will get hidden